# Unicode symbols fail for Proof-general while writing Coq

Tags: unicode, coq, proof-general

I use Coq 8.11 in Ubuntu with Proof-general. I write:

> Ltac example1 :=
>     fail.

and succeed. Say I want to use unicode symbols:

Proof-General -> Display -> Quick Options -> Unicode Tokens

then I write again:

> Ltac example2 ≔
>     fail.

and fail with the error:

> Error: Syntax Error: Lexer: Undefined token

So I go to some editor and write the sequence ":=" and copy paste it while writing:

> Ltac example3 :=
>     fail.

Happily I succeed again.

---

The above occurs with many symbols you can think of |-, /\, /, etc.

How can i solve it?

Comment: Perhaps reporting this as an issue on PG's GitHub would work better -- https://github.com/ProofGeneral/PG/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there is a difference between displaying Unicode tokens, and recognizing Unicode tokens as input.

Displaying Unicode tokens works as a sort of visual ligature, while the underlying text remains ASCII.  It means, you type `:=`, and the editor displays `≔`, but if you open with another editor, you will still see `:=`.

Now if you want to **use** Unicode tokens in your code, you can, but you need to let the Coq process know that you are doing so, by importing the `Unicode.Utf8` module:

```
From Coq Require Import Unicode.Utf8.
```